# Pretty print a JSON.dump 2d array in Python

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array, pretty-print

I'm writing a python tile map editor. I was using a self designed code to write and parse some files but the code was very confusing, so I switched to JSON for simplicity.

My json file is hand made like this:

```
{ "Level" :

     {

    "levelName": "simpleLevel",

    "background":   [[12, 2,12, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
                     [ 1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8,12, 3],
                     [ 1, 3, 1, 3,12,10,10, 1,12,12],
                     [ 2,12, 0, 4,10, 3,12, 2,12,12],
                     [12,12, 1, 1,10, 3,12, 2,12, 1],
                     [12,12,12, 0,10, 2, 1,12, 1,12],
                     [ 3,12, 3,12, 0, 2, 2,12,12, 3],
                     [ 1,12, 1,12, 1, 1,12,12, 3,12],
                     [ 3,12, 0,12,12,12,12,12, 3, 3],
                     [12, 3, 1, 2, 3,12,12,12, 1,12]],

    "foreground":   [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    }
}
```

But, when I use `json.dump(self.x, f)` my output is in a single line, and when I try to use these parameter `sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')` I get a thousand linefeeds..

I just want something similar with my handmade file because it's easier to read and edit by hand. I could find some solutions to simple arrays but nothing that worked for 2d arrays. Is there a simple answer or should I code myself?

edit:

coded myself (with some help from the web..)

```
def fwriteKeyVals(data, f, indent=0):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        f.write( "\n" + "    " * indent + "[" )  
        for i in range(len(data) ):  
            if ( i == 0):
                f.write( "[" )  
            else:
                f.write( "    " * indent + " [" )
            for j in range(len(data[0])):  
                f.write( "%3d" % data[i][j] )  
                f.write( "," ) if j != len(data[0])-1 else (f.write( "]," ) if i != len(data)-1 else f.write( "]" ))  
            f.write( "\n" ) if i != len(data)-1 else f.write( "]" )  
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        f.write( "\n" + "    " * indent + "{" )
        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            f.write( "\n" + "    " * indent + "\"" + k + "\"" + ": ")
            fwriteKeyVals(v, f, indent + 1)
            if( data.keys()[-1] != k):
                 f.write( "," )
        f.write( "\n" + "    " * indent + "}" )
    else:
        f.write("\"" + data + "\"")
```

Usage is:

```
fwriteKeyVals(x, f)
```

Where `x = json.load(f)` and `f` is the file I've loaded with `f = open( map , "wb" )`.

Comment: If you just do `indent=4` (without `separators`) you should get something pretty similar to what you're after; at least, it's always been close enough for my liking.

Comment: This is a handmade level in a computer game that I've already made a lot of levels, and now I've decided to make an appropriate level editor since it's tiresome doing level design looking just to a matrix of numbers - but I still would like to have that option available if needed. I'm also a newbie in Python - game is html5+js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, coded myself. Some hacks to print \n instead of real linefeed.

```
def fwriteKeyVals(data, f, indent=0):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        try:
            gotdata = isinstance(data[0], list)
        except IndexError:
            gotdata = False

        if gotdata:

            f.write( "\n" + "    " * indent + "[" )  
            for i in range(len(data) ):  
                if ( i == 0):
                    f.write( "[" )  
                else:
                    f.write( "    " * indent + " [" )
                for j in range(len(data[0])):  
                    f.write( "%3d" % data[i][j] )  
                    f.write( "," ) if j != len(data[0])-1 else (f.write( "]," ) if i != len(data)-1 else f.write( "]" ))  
                f.write( "\n" ) if i != len(data)-1 else f.write( "]" )  
        else:
            try:
                gotdata = data[0]
            except IndexError:
                gotdata = 'False'

            if gotdata is not 'False':
                f.write( " [" ) 
                for i in range(len(data) ): 
                    if isinstance(data[i], Number):
                        f.write( "%3d" % data[i] )   
                    else:
                        dataListLf = data[i].split("\n")
                        dataToWrite = dataListLf[0]
                        for line in dataListLf[1:]:
                            dataToWrite += '\\n'+line

                        f.write( "\"" + dataToWrite + "\"")
                    f.write( "," ) if i != len(data)-1 else f.write( "]" )
            else:
                f.write( " [\"\"]" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pprint.html), a Python module for Python data-structures. The following code should give you the print you want:

```
# x -> your json dict
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(x)
```

Comment: I get weird `u`letters in my pprint and it also gets wrong 2 things: no new line after `"Level" :`and doesn't used fixed number of caracters inside matrix, making the first matrix harder to read than the second, can it at least show left hand zeros?

`f=open('simpleLevel.json', "rb")
import json
x = json.load(f)
f.close()
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(x)
{   u'Level': {   u'background': [   [12, 2, 12, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
                                     [1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 3], ...`

Comment: The "u letters" are unicode encoding of your characters (for example, instead of `level` you get `u'level'`). Remove unicode encoding if that's the case. About the indentations, it gives one space between a comma and a number. That's reasonable, I don't see any reason why overcomplicate things. And what do you mean by 'left hand zeros'?

Comment: @Belphegor - I assume he wants the 0s to be left aligned.  Honestly, at that point it would probably be easier to just write your own formatter.  It's a pretty straightforward recursive problem.

Comment: @sapi I'm doing just that right now... I really thought there was a nicer way available.